# Perfrom CRUD operation on salesforce database using web based java application

Tags: apex

I want to create a web based java application that connects to Salesforce and need to perform CRUD operation on salesforce database.

The java application will open as a web tab inside my salesforce account.

I dont want again to login to my web based application.

Same salesforce account details should be used to perfrom CRUD operation on salesforce database.

I have tried using SSO but unable to solve issue.

If possible can you post some example.

Comment: Hi Kapil, Welcome to Salesforce Stackexchange. Your question is likely to be closed in it's current form. Could you elaborate some more on the methods you've already explored? And could you post some actual problems that you are encountering?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Cavas API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/canvas_framework.pdf) (Currently in pilot) you will be able to connect to your web application and send signed requests back to Salesforce from within a Salesforce tab.

Which tabs you can use are going to be limited (but I heard from the developers on Canvas last night as a developers meet-up that they are going to expand where you can place the Canvas apps within Salesforce

Comment: Thanks Lex I will try Canvas API and let you know !!! Thanks Jordan.. I have tried using Single sign on (SSO) using OAuth , Various authentications given by salesforce like (Fedral , Delegated).. But using above all solutions I am unable to get User details like (username , password , token) which as per my understanding I require for doing CRUD operation...

Comment: I tried using canvas API. But from pdf i am not getting a clearer ided.Can you please help by giving some example. I want to integrate a web app which should appear by click of a tab inside salesforce app. also I should be able to pass User details (username,password,token) to web app. Thanks for help in advance.